# Is there "static" like access modifier or something else to have access without instance creation but only inside of instance of app?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

One way to describe what I need is the following sample:

I have a main app class:

```
public class MyApp {
    var obj1 = new SomeClass1();
    var obj2 = new SomeClass2();
}
```

I have some other class that are used in MyApp:

```
public class SomeClass1() {}
public class SomeClass2() {}
```

I can run some instances of MyApp in the same time.

I want to declare a CommonClass like this:

```
public class CommonClass {
     public void Method() {
          // do something
     }
}
```

and I want to have an access to CommonClass.Method() in SomeClass1 and SomeClass2 without CommonClass instance creation.

Looks like "static" access modifier, right?

But I have a problem: any of MyApp instances have common CommonClass if I will use "static" modifier. I need a solution like static class (no need in instance creation), but one per MyApp instance.

Any idea to solve the problem?

**Update 1:**
I have tried to use "internal", but still have a problem:

```
internal class CommonClass {
    private static List<SomeMyType> _objects;
    public static void Method(SomeMyType obj) {
        // 1) Called from the first instance of MyApp - _objects is 
        // empty, I can add or delete objects from _objects list.
        // 2) Called from the second instance of MyApp (the first 
        // instance of MyApp still runned) - ooops, _objects isn't empty
        // if I added an object in my first MyApp instance.
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

So I have two possible ways:

1) I create two instances of CommonClass. One per MyApp instance. But with this way, I should to pass a reference of CommonClass object to SomeClass1 and SomeClass2, but I want to call a method of CommonClass inside SomeClass1 and SomeClass2 like "CommonClass.Method()" and don't pass a reference.

2) I can use static class and call it like i want "CommonClass.Method()" inside SomeClass1 and SomeClass2, but so I have one instance per MyApp type, not per MyApp instance.

My conclusion: The only way to solve the problem is a creation of instances of CommonClass and pass a reference of CommonClass to SomeClass1 and SomeClass2.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "instance of my app". Are those two separate processes? I mean one .exe file is started twice?

Comment: This information can be useful: MyApp is an ActiveX control that I can integrate in other app. I can add any number of same ActiveX controls to other app. One instance of MyApp means one ActiveX control object.

Comment: Also I have marked a CommonClass with an attribute [ComVisible(false)], but the problem still exists.

Comment: As you want two copies of the data structure, you will need to create two instances of it. If you use static it creates one instance which everything using it shares.

Comment: @RobAnthony Please look at Update 2 in a question description and tell me  - am I right? Is there no other solutions?

Comment: Hi. Could you maybe post the code where you actually use these classes, as it's not really clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: But you might want to include a  static CommonClass as a property/field in each of SomeClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You're looking for the [`internal` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal).
The `internal` modifier makes the class (or a method) accessible from the assembly within it is declared, but not from other assemblies.</s>

So your code should look like this:

```
internal class CommonClass {
     public static void Method() {
          // do something
     }
}
```

Or, if you'd like the class to be accessible from any assembly, but the method to be accessible only to you, you could do:

```
public class CommonClass {
     internal static void Method() {
          // do something
     }
}
```

### UPDATE

As per your edit, it is clear that you don't have an access scope issue, so the `internal` modifier is not the solution. 
Since you need an instance per ActiveX control you definitely need to create it.

Comment: I have tried to use your suggestion, but I still have a problem. Please look an **Update 1** section in question description.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance to solve your problem (if i have understood your requirements correctly).

I believe you want to be able to be able to use the properties and mentors of CommonClass in both SomeClass1 and SomeClass2 without having to create new instances of CommonClass in SomeClass1 and SomeClass2.

If you make SomeClass1 and SomeClass2 inherit from CommonClass, you will have all the methods and properties of CommonClass avaiable to both SomeClass1 and SomeClass2.  See below for an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj1 = new SomeClass1();
        var obj2 = new SomeClass2();

        obj1._objects.Add(3);
        obj2._objects.Add(7);

        Console.WriteLine(obj1.Method());
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.Method());
    }
}

public class SomeClass1 : CommonClass
{
}
public class SomeClass2 : CommonClass
{
}

public class CommonClass
{
    public List<int> _objects;
    public int Method()
    {
    return this._objects[0];
    }
    public CommonClass()
    {
        _objects = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

When this code is executed, 3 is added to the list in obj1 and 7 to the list in obj2 and Method() is executed for both objects. They return 3 and 7, as they should.

The code is available in a [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0jXkri), if you want to see it working.